# Extracting strings from a file to another using python3 turns out TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python-3.x

The code I am trying to compile is producing a TypeError in the Python shell,
however, when I change the out_file PATH as concrete strings, it works as desired. Can someone please help me figure out what is producing this error?

The .fasta file is series of amino sequences with special header line like this:

```
 >sp|Q6GZX4|001R_FRG3G Putative transcription factor 001R OS=Frog virus 3 (isolate Goorha) OX=654924 GN=FV3-001R PE=4 SV=1
MAFSAEDVLKEYDRRRRMEALLLSLYYPNDRKLLDYKEWSPPRVQVECPKAPVEWNNPPS
EKGLIVGHFSGIKYKGEKAQASEVDVNKMCCWVSKFKDAMRRYQGIQTCKIPGKVLSDLD
AKIKAYNLTVEGVEGFVRYSRVTKQHVAAFLKELRHSKQYENVNLIHYILTDKRVDIQHL
EKDLVKDFKALVESAHRMRQGHMINVKYILYQLLKKHGHGPDGPDILTVKTGSKGVLYDD
SFRKIYTDLGWKFTPL
```

Below is my code:

```
fasta_file = open('/Users/apple/Desktop/123.fasta','r')

seq = ''
for line in fasta_file:
    if line[0] == '>' and seq == '':
        head = line
        AC = line.split('|')
    elif line[0] != '>' and seq == '':
        seq = seq + line 
    elif line[0] == '>' and seq != '':
        out_file = open(AC,'w')
        out_file.write(head + line)
        out_file.close()
        seq=''
        head=line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 8 try this,

1. line=line.join(" ")
2. seq=seq+ line

.
.
.

Comment: Your answer combined with the other answer make up a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
seq = seq + line
```

Clearly from your code `line` is a list as you are indexing it in the previous line. But `seq` is a string. Python is complaining that the `+` operator can't be used to add a list to a string.

I'm not certain what you are trying to accomplish so I can't really suggest a fix. If you are trying to add the line to `seq`, then you would need to choose which element of `line` you want to add it to (e.g. `seq + line[0]`). If you want to add `seq` as (say) the last element of `line`, then you would use `line.append(seq)`, for instance.